# Python equivalent for Ruby's pack function

Tags: python, endianness

I'm translating some of my old Ruby scripts into Python and I have trouble finding a function in Python that belongs to Ruby:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M002222.html - which keeps the array in little endian byte order. Is there any Python module that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array) module of Python's standard library may offer somewhat-similar functionality (though it's definitely not an exact match). It does not force endianness (you can swap items' endianness with method `byteswap`) and does not intrinsically keep items as "a string" (you can convert back and forth with methods `tostring` and `fromstring`) but it may be worth looking at, depending on how you're using the Ruby `pack` function I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The Python [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) built-in allows you to "cast" an array or any bytes-like object to different endianess. Se the [.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.cast) method. The great thing about memoryviews is that they operate without copying bytes: they share memory with the source data structure.